# Share highscore to users Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, sharing

I am in the process of creating my third android game. It is nearly done, only one detail left, the "Share highscore to facebook" button. I have noooo clue how to make a connection from my app to the users facebook?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/checklist
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements

To be able to share your score to Facebook, you need to implement Facebook Login for Android:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/